# addEventListener("input", callback) doesn't work in opera?

Tags: javascript, browser, opera, dom-events

I'm trying to listen to "oninput" event, but something is wrong with Opera:

```
document.getElementById("i1").oninput = function(){
    console.log("inputting");
};
document.getElementById("i1").addEventListener("input", function(){
    console.log("inputting");
});
```

The first one works, but the second one doesn't work....it this a bug of opera?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn2zS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out this myself, `addEventListener` has a 3rd parameter, it can be ignored in Chrome but not other browsers.

Comment: The DOM events spec was changed recently to make the third argument optional, Opera will follow but for now it's best to keep the third argument for best compatibility.

Comment: This was added to Opera in version 11.60.