# What event name use in Opera's userJS to trigger a function when page finished loading and has downloaded all its assets like img,script,css etc.?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, opera, userjs

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function () {
  alert(document.getElementsByTagName("DIV").length);
}, false);
//'load' event above doesn't show any response, alert isn't showing

alert(document.getElementsByTagName("DIV").length);
// this alert returns 0 it looks like it is called before the page DOM has loaded

window.onload = function() {
 alert(document.getElementsByTagName("DIV").length);
};
//returns 0, what the... it seems DOM hasn't loaded also
// but only on some sites, here on stackoverflow and youtube it works,
//but on google.com and many other websites (pcworld.com) shows 0
```

The same situation in latest stable and alpha Operas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simply do

`window.addEventListener('load', function(){}, false)`

like you would in a normal script. You could use  `opera.addEventListener('BeforeEvent.load', ...)` but that might not fire if the page's scripts do not listen for load events in some Opera versions.

Some other background reading:
[window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

[addEventListener("input", callback) doesn't work in opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709818/addeventlistenerinput-callback-doesnt-work-in-opera)